# Edit.GoToAll command in Visual Studio does not show file name suggestions

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

**Context**

I use this command with the shortcut Ctrl + T (alternatively Ctrl + ,) to quickly navigate to files in my solution (WPF app if relevant). As I do not remember the exact file names I would (until recently) use the suggestions that were showing below the prompt to find my files as in this example:

[Navigation with suggestions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vT70z.png)
[Source of example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ofsdVKrMg8I&t=2584s)

Since I last started VS I get none:

[Navigation without suggestions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWxZO.png)

**Attempts**

Restarting and updating visual studio didn't help. Neither did deleting the .vs file of the solution. I also toggled the statement completion fields in Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages, saw no change.

I believe this might be some Intellisense error but I am not sure. I would be thankful for any guidance or information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible cause is somehow you had collapsed the list. If you hover over the point in the picture below you should get a resize handle. Grab it and pull it down to get your list back.
[image]

Comment: That was it, thank you! I would never have thought resizing could be the issue.